# how to set custom product name/ title in amazon product listing useing M2epro in magento?

Tags: magento, m2e-pro

how to set custom product name/ title in amazon product listing using M2epro in magento?

I am using M2EPRO VERSION 6.0.3

I dont want use custom attribute option avaialble in admin.

I want to change it programitcally.